# Cannot use phpdoc command globally

Tags: windows, environment-variables, phpdoc

I installed [phpDocumentor 2.*](http://phpdoc.org/) in the directory `D:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor` according to the `composer.json` in the same directory using Composer.
It installed all dependencies required by phpDocumentor.

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
    }
}
```

When I navigate to the directory `D:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\bin` via Windows Command Line and run `phpdoc`, it is fine.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\TPP>cd\

C:\>d:

D:\>cd xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\bin

D:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\bin>phpdoc --version
phpDocumentor version 2.7.0

D:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\bin>
```

I added the path `D:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\bin` in Windows Environment Variable, but I could not access `phpdoc` globally.

```
C:\Users\TPP>phpdoc
******************************************************************************
* PhpDocument Command-Line  Starter
*
* phpDocumentor is a JavaDoc-like automatic documentation generator for PHP
* written in PHP. It is the most versatile tool for documenting PHP.
*
* This batch-file will try to run the phpDocumentor using the command-line
* version of PHP4. NOTE: It will not run with the PHP ISAPI module!
* Please update the path in this batch-file to your PHP-CLI.
*
* Tip: o Grab a copy of one of the ini-files in the user/ dir of the
*        phpDocumentor and modify the settings there.
*      o To see the command line options type  phpdoc -h
*
* @version 1.3  2003-06-28
* @author Sam Blum sam@blueshoes.org
* @Copyright Free Software released under the GNU/GPL license
*
* This SW was contributed by BlueShoes www.blueshoes.org "The PHP Framework"
******************************************************************************
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select Ini-File [default is phpDocumentor.ini]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 0: phpDocumentor.ini
Type a number and press Enter[0]:0
Starting: "D:\xampp\php\.\php.exe" "D:\xampp\php\phpdoc" -c "phpDocumentor.ini"

Could not open input file: \xampp\php\phpdoc
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\Users\TPP>
```

It seems to be conflicting with `D:\xampp\php\phpdoc` which likely comes with PHP installation. I use  [XAMPP 1.8.0](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) with PHP 5.4.4.

How can I make `phpdoc` run globally according to my new installation?

Answer (score 0):

That is phpDocumentor 1.x being included with the other PEAR packages that come with XAMPP.  The best option would be to use XAMPP's PEAR executable to uninstall phpDocumentor **before** using Composer to install phpDocumentor 2.x.  Any other means to uninstall 1.x will probably leave some old files lying around.

Answer (score 0):

Install **PHP Documentor**

`C:\> composer global require phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor`

Determine you **composer global path**

`C:\> composer global config home`

Set the global composer libraries to your **system's environment path**

`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

Confirm setup

`C:\> phpdoc --version`